# Left/right positioning takes border size into account

Tags: html, css

My goal is to be able to dynamically position a DIV so that it is visually precisely underneath it's parent - i.e. so that it is the same width as it's parent, and begins 0 pixels from the bottom of the parent's left border.

Essentially, the end result should be something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cvz3gvbs/

Here I simply use a relatively positioned parent DIV, and an absolutely positioned child DIV.  I then simply use the `left` and `top` positioning attributes to move the child DIV into place.

However, you'll notice in that fiddle that in order to make this happen, I had to set `left: -10px` on the child DIV.  The reason is that if I don't, this happens:

http://jsfiddle.net/cvz3gvbs/1/

Here, the child DIV is *not* directly centered underneath the parent.  The reason seems to be that the `left` and `right` position values take into account the *border* of the parent, so that `left: 0px` means positioned directly to the right of where the parent border ends.

So I have to compensate for this with a negative `left` value.  That's fine, except if I want to be able to do this dynamically with Javascript, I might not know in advance the thickness of the parent border - (or even if the parent even *has* a border).  So I can't simply hardcode a negative pixel value in the style sheet.  I'd have to use Javascript to dynamically query the computed styles of the parent element and determine the border width of the parent, which is a bit cumbersome.

**Question:** Is there some way to do this *without* using Javascript to discover the border width?

I thought this might have something to do with the [W3C box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), since `left` was taking into account the border of the parent.  So, I tried using the `box-sizing: border-box` property so that the browser would include the border-width in the box size - but this had no effect.  A `left` value of `0px` still means positioned directly to the right of the parent element's border.

Comment: Possibly adding moz-box-sizing: border-box; for mozilla might resolve the issue, since the box-sizing is what you're looking for as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm using chrome, so I don't think it's a mozilla problem

Comment: No, `box-sizing` will not fix this issue; the reference points for absolute positioning are determined by the _containing block_ of the element, and that includes padding and borders of the relative positioned parent element. But depending on what you are actually trying to achieve here there might be other ways to solve this, but this minimal example leaves that quite ambiguous – so an example closer to what the actual end result and behavior is supposed to be might be helpful.

Comment: Using a proper `reset css`(or for this example setting `html` and `body` padding to 0) and placing the containers next to each other [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/cvz3gvbs/2/). Styling containers to exceed their parent is btw. always a bad idea (except when using `overflow:hidden/scroll` on the parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a necessisty that `.bar` be inside `.foo`? You could make them siblings and wrap them in a container set to `relative` like so. You don't even need to set the `width` on each of them, just on their parent:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class = "foo"></div>
   <div class = "bar"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.foo {
  border: 10px solid #000000;
  height: 45px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.bar {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 500px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvz3gvbs/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You should add them in a container like this example

```
<div>
    <div class = "foo"></div>

    <div class = "bar"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cvz3gvbs/6/

and you can remove the position of the class bar